# Is there any possibility of starting multiple fiddler sessions in a single desktop programatically in C#?

Tags: fiddler

I wanted to start multiple fiddler sessions in a single desktop programatically in c#.
Is there any possibility for that?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple fiddler sessions?  Do you want to chain them?  Have you looked at the fiddler API?  If so, what have you looked into, and why won't it work for you?

Comment: Excellent questions. (you can only run one instance of Fiddler itself in capturing mode; additional viewers can be started with the -viewer command line option). If you've written your own app with FiddlerCore, you can run as many instances of that as you want.

Answer (score 12):

It's possible to have multiple Fiddler viewers (fiddler running in Viewer Mode), but it's not possible to have multiple capturing sessions. To be honest, there shouldn't be a need to have multiple capturing sessions.

For fiddler running in viewer mode I'd recommend a desktop shortcut to:

```
<Fiddler location> -viewer
```

e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\Fiddler.exe" -viewer
```

Comment: "There shouldn't be a need" What if I want to listen on multiple ports?

Answer (score 7):

Within an existing Fiddler session

```
File -> New Viewer
```

The viewer has no capture facility, but is great for loading past captures for manual comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the question is two open two Fiddler instances for proxy chaining.So Can we have two instances running on different ports where one instance1->instance2->UpStream Proxy or Instance2-AutoResponse  ?

Answer (score -1):

also right click on the 2nd fiddler file and select "open in viewer" then no command line options are needed

BasicTek

Comment: The OP specifically said he/she is looking for programmatic or script solutions, not GUI based one.